# Lmer R: linear mixed model with random intercepts and nested variables

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, intercept

I want to write a model for my data on cell counts in specific brain regions. The multilevel structure of the data is as follows:

- Measurements within subregions with axes within animal
- Subregion and axis are categorical

The model I am trying to create is as follows:

- a random intercept for axis (within animal) and a random intercept for subregion nested within axis
- this is equivalent to random intercept for axis*subregion within animal

My question is how I can translate this to R.

I have tried 3 different models but I am not sure if any of them is correct.

```r
Model1 <- lmer(Density.tdT ~ Group * Axis * Subregion + 
                          (1| Animal_ID), data = data)

Model2 <- lmer(Density.tdT ~ Group*Axis*Subregion + 
                          (1| Animal_ID/Axis/Subregion), data = data)

region <- factor(data$Axis:data$Subregion)
Model3 <- lmer(Density.tdT ~ Group*Axis*Subregion + 
                          (1| Animal_ID/region), data = data)
```